# Block Network Manager from showing a specific wifi or even using it

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I think I have a unique issue here I need some help with...  My 15 year old has gotten tricky on me and is using my neighbors wifi to go around my router protections (I use opendns).  I have asked my neighbor to change their wifi password, but it seems like they haven't, so he continues to game on their wifi, since mine blocks access to gaming during certain times of the day.

How do I "banlist" my neighbors network wifi from being used.  I've seen several posts on how to forget the network, etc., but my son is too smart for that.  Other that changing the sudo password after I remove the neighbors network is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Let's see how smart your 15 yo is. Open the Wi-Fi settings for your neighbor's Wi-Fi. Disable the "Automatically Connect", and set the IPv4 and IPv6 to "Disabled", and set the password to xyz.

Comment: I'll will try  that, not a bad idea.!